# Is it possible to alter a SQL Server table column datatype from bigint to varchar after it has been populated?

Tags: sql-server, types

I have a SQL Server 2008 table which contains an external user reference currently stored as a bigint - the userid from the external table. I want to extend this to allow email address, open ID etc to be used as the external identifier. Is it possible to alter the column datatype from bigint to varchar without affecting any of the existing data?

Comment: Yes you can - providing you define the `varchar` size big enough.  SQL Server will throw an error if it isn't big enough

Comment: I assume you're adding an additional column also, that tells you what type of external identifier you've stored? Or are 100% sure that the domains of these values don't overlap, or if they do that you don't need a means to distinguish between them?

Comment: Yes, there's another column to identify the source of the external reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible, no problem - as long as you make your `VARCHAR` field big enough to hold you BIGINT values :-)

You'd have to use something like this T-SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ALTER COLUMN YourColumnName VARCHAR(50)   -- or whatever you want
```

and that should be it! Since all `BIGINT` values can be converted into a string, that command should work just fine and without any danger of losing data.

Comment: Behind the scenes however SQL Server will continue allocating space for the old `bigint` column until the clustered index is rebuilt.

Comment: I should add, that you have to remove any Primary Key indices on the columns before you do this; then, add them back when done.  Also, if you have any relationships defined on these columns, you must first delete them then add them back when done.

Comment: One other problem I am having, is after executing the ALTER commands, the database diagram is still showing the column as BIGINT.  This is even after I disconnected and reconnected SSMS, hoping that would refresh the schema.  Editing the table itself afterwards also shows it still as BIGINT, even though the T-SQL commands executed without error.